# Unable to connect to Bluetooth Mate in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to connect my laptop running ubuntu 12.04 to a Bluetooth Mate Silver connected to an arduino.

Wiring is :

```
CTS-I->No connection (leave floating)
VCC->5V
GND->GND
TX-O->D2
RX-I->D3
RTS-O->No connection (leave floating)
```

Code running on arduino :

```
$include <SoftwareSerial.h>  

int bluetoothTx = 2;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D2
int bluetoothRx = 3;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D3

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Begin the serial monitor at 9600bps

  bluetooth.begin(115200);  // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
  bluetooth.print("$$$");  // Enter command mode
  delay(100);  // Short delay, wait for the Mate to send back CMD
  bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");  // Temporarily Change the baudrate to 9600, no parity
  // 115200 can be too fast at times for NewSoftSerial to relay the data reliably
  bluetooth.begin(9600);  // Start bluetooth serial at 9600
}

void loop()
{
  if(bluetooth.available())  // If the bluetooth sent any characters
  {
    // Send any characters the bluetooth prints to the serial monitor
    Serial.print((char)bluetooth.read());  
  }
  if(Serial.available())  // If stuff was typed in the serial monitor
  {
    // Send any characters the Serial monitor prints to the bluetooth
    bluetooth.print((char)Serial.read());
  }
  // and loop forever and ever!
}
```

When I open the bluetooth manager in ubuntu I find that the bluetooth mate is visible but unknown and there is no SPP connection option when I right click on it. All the tutorials and blogs I went through connected to bluetooth mate through the SPP option.

Pic of my bluetooth manager : http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/12001550/640/12001550.jpg

So now how do I connect to the bluetooth mate?

Comment: you should ask at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I did... but did not find any replies. Anyway I found the answer after spending a whole day googling and reading various blogs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of googling and reading various blogs I came across this command :

```
    sudo rfcomm bind 0 00:06:66:48:71:0C
```

where 00:06:66:48:71:0C is the mac address of the bluetooth mate silver.

Once I did that I found that the serial port option for my device in the bluetooth manager was enabled. 
I continue from there to connect to the device.

Comment: How do you send commands to the bluetooth interface from the PC? What about sending a number to Arduino?